# What is the best way to find a object inside TreeSet based on internal field?

Tags: java, search, collections, treeset

I have the following object in a `TreeSet<MyObject>`:

```
public class MyObject implements Comparable<MyObject> {
    private Long id;
    private String Name;

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I would like to search if an element of `id = 5` exists in this `TreeSet`. How can I do this?

Comment: Your objects are not `Comparable` to each other, so your `TreeSet` must be using a `Comparator`, which you have not presented.  How you could best do what you ask depends on the order defined by that `Comparator`.

Comment: Do you have a `TreeMap` or a `TreeSet`? Your title and post are conflicting.

Comment: You don't have to search.  No instance of the class presented has an `id` of 5, because that field is `private`, it is not set by the class's (default) constructor, and there is no method to modify it.  Every instance has `id == 0`.

Comment: After the edit, there is now a way that an instance could have an `id` of 5, but there is still no way to check the `id` of any instance.  Moreover, your code now does not compile, because class `MyObject` is not `abstract` but does not provide an implementation of `Comparable.compareTo(MyObject)`.  The details of that method matter!

Comment: @JohnBollinger thank you for clarify. I already have a compareTo method, but i would like to create another one. so i think the Comparator as you said, will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this：

```
Iterator<MyObject> it = set.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
     MyObject object = it.next();
     if(object.id==5){
        // find it
     }
}
```

Comment: And if he did try that then it would not compile, because `MyObject.id` is `private`.